# Why does the ragged2e package screw up my emphasized text and headings?

Tags: macros, luatex, emphasis, ragged2e

I encountered a weird behavior of the **ragged2e** package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}     
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\ir}[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}                     


\begin{document}

\section{Here it works!}

\emph{\blindtext}

\begin{align}
G(s) = \frac{i(s)}{u(s)} = \frac{ 1 }{R_{42} + s L_{1984} } \:.
\end{align}


\section{Here everything gets screwed up!}

\begin{align}
G(s) = \frac{i(s)}{u(s)} = \frac{ 1 }{R\ir{Cu} + s L\ir{eff}(s)} \:.
\end{align}

\section{Here it doesn't work}

\emph{\blindtext}


\end{document}
```

which will give:

[image]

The second emphasized text is screwed up and the heading as well.

---

**What's wrong with my macro**

```
\newcommand{\ir}[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}
```

**that the following parts turn out so badly?**

---

**Why does this behaviour just occur when the ragged2e package is loaded?**

---

**It think the macro is not the real problem, what alternatives to ragged2e do I have?**

---

I have used the macro a thousand times in my thesis, and changing the notation from `\ir{...}` to `\somethingElse{...}` does not change the behaviour.

I need `ragged2e` to create my nomenclature, one will find its usage in this context a various times here on tex.se.

I use **luaLatex** and my Miktex distribution was updated today. (Actually I'm not sure, if the problem was there before the update, as I'm changing a lot of things at the moment).

Comment: Lualatex run breaks with assertion failure, with `pdflatex` there is no issue

Comment: @HarishKumar: With `lualatex` or with `pdflatex`

Comment: You should report this to the luatex maintainers, a failed assertion is never a user error. `ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macrosassertion "varmem[(p)].hh.v.RH!=null" failed: file "../../../texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/mlist.w", line 2542, function: make_ord
Aborted (core dumped)
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, the same error as I noticed

Comment: @ChristianHupfer With xe and pdflatex, it works. With lua, `process is killed!`

Comment: @HarishKumar: Yes, I can confirm for `xelatex` too. Strange stuff with lualatex

Comment: It seems to be connected with `\mathrm` ... Without it, the lualatex run works (no failure) and the text is as it should be

Comment: The problem does not occur if I load the `fontspec` package. (System: MacOSX 10.10.3, MacTeX2014, all the latest updates installed.)

Comment: Reported here http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2015-April/005158.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks David! I was just searching where I could report it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already fixed in luatex from current TeX Live trunk svn. The Debian binaries for unstable and testing (soon stable) are based on newer svn versions, and don't exhibit this behaviour. So you need to update to newer luatex, either by compiling it yourself, or waiting for TL2015.

Comment: does it make a difference, that I use MikTex and not TexLive? will the bug be solved in general for both distributions?

Comment: @thewaywewalk probably you should report it to miktex, then Christian can pull the latest luatex sources into miktex builds at some point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle reported  [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2361/), hope it's alright.

Comment: @thewaywewalk looks like the right place